# matplotlib right click to zoom not working

Tags: macos, matplotlib, zooming, x11, right-click

When running matplotlib in interactive mode the figure should zoom when you drag while holding down the right mouse button. This is not working for me. It will zoom if I drag with the left mouse button while holding down the option key.

Does anyone know how to get the right mouse button working for zooming? Is it an issue with matplotlib, ipython, x11, settings in system preferences?

Here is a description of how things are supposed to work (look under 'Pan/Zoom'):
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/navigation_toolbar.html

I'm running Enthought python distribution 7.2.2 64 bit on OSX 10.5.8. The matplotlib plots are displayed in an X11 window and the backend is TkAgg.

Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that zoom IS working, just with the mouse wheel button (middle button) instead of the right click. This is pretty annoying and according to the link I posted it should be using the right click button to zoom.

Does anyone know what's going on here/how to switch the zoom feature to the right mouse button?

Answer (score 1):

In the TkAgg backend the mouse button numbers are hardcoded so there is no easy rc setting to change. I do notice that there is some special case code in the tkagg backend (~ line 351):

```
    if sys.platform=='darwin':
        # 2 and 3 were reversed on the OSX platform I
        # tested under tkagg
        if   num==2: num=3
        elif num==3: num=2
```

Which looks very suspicious given your problem. Perhaps it is worth opening a [matplotlib issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/new), and giving some details as to the type of mouse you are using (plus all of the details in the original, well put together, question).